# Android: ACTION_OUTSIDE MotionEvent X and Y return 0 solved?

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouch

I'm encountering a known bug where `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` doesn't return location for `ACTION_OUTSIDE` events on 4.2+.

Therefore, `MotionEvent` X and Y return 0.

This bug is reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72746).

Does anyone know if this bug is solved or know any workaround?

Comment: can we have some code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was solved it would say so in the issue report. Therefore it is **not solved**

Comment: The issue status is "Won't Fix (Obsolete)", so not only it is not fixed but there is no intention for it to ever be worked on.